# linking two shared objects via static object in executable

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

This appears to be a pretty specific question, couldn't find the answer on these pages anyway... Here goes:

I have a static library containing:

```
/** --- libstatic.a / foo.h --- */
struct foo {
...
}
extern "C" CreateFoo();
```

A shared library containing:

```
/** libshared_one.so / myFoo.cpp */
#include <foo.h>
struct myFoo {
...
}
extern "C" foo* CreateFoo() {
 return new myFoo;
}
```

Another shared library containing this:

```
/** --- libshared_two.so / foo_factory.cpp */
#include <foo.h>
extern "C" {
    void* new_Foo(...) {
      foo* arg0 = CreateFoo();
      return (void*)arg0;
    }
}
```

Now, in my application; I statically link libstatic.a and dynamically load (via dlopen) both  my shared objects (dlopen("libshared_one.so") / dlopen("libshared_two.so). I'm expecting libshared_two.so's CreateFoo() call to be linked to the "strong" version. However, I get

```
undefined symbol: CreateFoo
```

nm -D ./libshared_two.so shows that CreateFoo is Undefined indeed, how do i get the linker (or specifically dlopen) to recognize the defined version of CreateFoo?

Comment: Simply link to your static library when you create your shared libraries. You can also, make a shared library out of your static library: if it's linked by your other shared libraries, it should be loaded in the moment you ask for them.

Comment: @Antonio That works in C++ now, however; I also need it in JAVA, using      System.loadLibrary(...)

Comment: Haven't used Java in looooong time, better for you to re-ask the question, putting the java tag.